# call warning windows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

```
declare @t table (code int,item int,[return] int,[action] int)
insert @t (code,item,[return],[action])
values
( 123 ,123 , 123 ,123),
(123 ,123 , 123 ,123),
( 123 ,123 , 123 ,123),
( 123 ,123 , 123 ,123)

select * from @t
```

we see that each row has 4 similar value(123)
Is it possible that 
if any row has different value (one or more), then run windows with alert
that row (suppose row five, has one or more different value)?

something like this
say this row five

```
( 123 ,123 , 123 ,124)
```

Alert
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It seems like a terrible idea

Comment: @holder,  I wait  your arguments why this is a bad idea. And I inform you that there are 4 tables in the sql, the value 123( is conditionally )the number of observations in the tables, in all 4 tables it should be the same, otherwise it is  terrible.

Comment: I constantly have to track every day. If you have a different approach to tracking the difference in the number of observations, I listen to you.

Comment: I don't question that you want to test your data. But I think popups is a bad/not feasible idea. I would suggest something like this:  select distinct *  from your table. If it returns more than one row it's not correct.

Comment: The correct solution is to create a trigger that prevents insertion of `(123,123, 123, 124)` and stop worrying.

Comment: @SalmanA, can you tell how do it?

Comment: Note 123 is not static value. tomorrow can be 125,125,125, 125 observation in tables

Comment: SQL Server itself has no UI. Whilst SSMS has a UI, it's already been written and doesn't have user definable popups as part of it. If you want something popping up, that's going to involve some other tech that you've not identified here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
select distinct code,item,[return],[action]  from your_table
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 1)
        BEGIN
             RAISERROR('error in table ',16,1)
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it with select case
I change my code as your comment.

```
create proc Notsamevalue (@Notsamevalue int)
as
    select case when code<>123 then 'code is not not same' 
        when item<>@Notsamevalue then 'code is  not same'
        when return<>@Notsamevalue then 'return is not same'
        when action<>@Notsamevalue then 'action is not same'
        else 'All items are same'
         end as stat
        from @T
go
exec Notsamevalue '123'
```

Comment: Note 123 is not static value. tomorrow can be 125,125,125, 125 observation in tables

Comment: I changed it as your request ;)